# Good project setup for a multi part project with Git and Node/Npm

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I'm currently planning a project that will have 3 differant parts, Restful server, the website and desktop app. This will be my first experience on a project this big using node/npm and i'm unsure how to setup the project directories.

For example is it best to store everything in one Git directory with its own npm package (for overall control for things such as gulp) and then a folder for each part inside here each with its own package.json. Or Is it considered better to have each part in its own Git and package manager?  Or any other setups that could be used?

My current thought is to split the server and front-end into two differant repositories for use on pushing onto VPS to differant locations, but there will be shared code between them (class files mainly) and unsure how to best handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its mainly a personal decission.

My approach would be to make 5 repos:

- Parent Repo
- Shared
- Rest
- Homepage
- App

Then you can combine all repos using git submodules. This gives you a seperate history/better overview over every part of the project while keeping the comfort of only fetching/pulling once.

(More information about submodules: [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules))

To keep the shared code really independent its a good idea to physically seperate it into a sepearte git repo and referencing it via npm.

So the directory structure could be like this:

```
| MyApp
|--- .git
|--- Configuration files/global stuff not directly related to the parts of the project (e. g. build config for all projects, editor config)
|--- Shared
     |--- .git
     |--- package.json
     |--- Source Files etc.
|--- Rest
     |--- .git
     |--- package.json
     |--- Source Files etc.
|--- App
     |--- .git
     |--- package.json
     |--- Source Files etc.
|--- Website
     |--- .git
     |--- package.json
     |--- Source Files etc.
```

Comment: Thanks this does seem like a good system. With submodules (never used before and seems daunting) folders is it best to have their own repo to upload too. Or just a empty "git init" and "git submodule add /folder"?

Comment: @Tristan I use it always with a server combination (e. g. gitlab) and own repo.